# OpsHub VSO migration error

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

I keep getting the following error when I try to migrate a TFS 2013 team project to Visual Studio Team Services. "*OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. Access to the path 'O:\w69_13\teamproject' denied.*"

I tried it a couple of times but each time it prompts with a different folder name. My login has full rights to the TFS_Temp folder.

Comment: What is happening in the changeset that is failing? Is it the first changeset of the project of the migration? Is this a project that was created as branch of another existing project?

Comment: This is the check in for project creation so the very first changeset. It is not a branch.

Comment: Is the machine OS windows 10?

Comment: Yes its Windows 10. I have also tried it from Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 2012 R2 servers.

Comment: Its a permission issue then. The TFS Service is not able to access a folder that was created by the OVSMU Tool Service.

Comment: Well what permission exactly do I need to give? And this permission needs to be given to the account that the TFS service runs under?

Comment: When the tool is running, go to "Task Manager" and under processes, search for OpsHub TFS Service, go to it's properties and set it to run as admin user.

Comment: Getting the same error. This time on folder "O:\w47_13"

Comment: This means the OpsHub service is not running as admin aswell\. Go to services, search for OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility and override the user running the service with Administrator

Comment: No that didn't work either. Same error.

Comment: Hi, the issue is very much explicit to user rights. Is there any way to involve your IT to verify if the user has enough rights. Or possible trying this out on a different machine temporarily where security is lax to verify exact cause.

Comment: I have also tried it from my laptop on which there are no restrictions and I am in the admin group on the latop. IT wont help unless there is a specific issue that I can point them at.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the migration utility does not have the Read&Write Permission to TFS_Temp folder. Check your machine security settings and try to run the utility as Administrator.

Comment: I did run it as administrator. I am also part of the collection administrators group on both TFS on-prem and VSO.